# GUI for Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Could you advice a GUI for working with Doctrine (Symfony2) on desktop (OS Linux) or browser for convenient work with tables: managing fields, content, relations between tables?

Comment: You have this tool: https://www.skipper18.com/ but it is expensive

Comment: I'm agree with @CarlosGranados, but SO forbid us to say that. So, don't say that...

Answer (score 1):

as referred by @CarlosGranados Skipper (http://www.skipper18.com) application does exactly what you need.

You can visually model and configure all ORM objects and it's properties and export it to schema files (for Doctrine it's YML, for Doctrine2 it's YML, XML and annotations).

To note about the price. Yes, it is expensive but it's because such tool is very complex and we have to continuously develop and maintain it because of changes in ORM frameworks. Also you will get lifetime license so as long as you don't need updates you can use it without any other payments.

To meet SO requirements, I'm chief developer of this tool.

Comment: I'm curious why -2 points?? Application does exactly what Kevin is asking for.